# getting GL_MODELVIEW 's value

Tags: c++, opengl

I used the following codes to check GL_MODELVIEW and GL_PROJECTION 's value.

```
GLdouble modelView[16] = {0};
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, modelView);
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i){
    std::cout << modelView[i] << '\t';
    if((i+1)%4 == 0)
        std::cout << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
```

However, I always get all zeros. could anybody tell me the reason?

```
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
 glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
```